# Moment js with highstock

Tags: highcharts, momentjs

For a highstock Graph, I want to set x-axis min value as 1 year before from today with 1-month intervals and max value as today. On clicking different checkboxes, I want to change this min value to one month before from today with I week interval and so on.
How can I use moment js with highstock for setting min, max values, and time intervals for the x-axis?
This is my dataset

```
["2019-11-10T18:59:51", 0.0024060238132714625]
["2019-12-10T18:59:51", 0.0024060238132714625]
["2019-12-10T19:00:59", 0.0023284197556864505]
["2019-12-10T19:02:07", 0.0021658971881996325]
["2019-12-10T19:03:15", 0.0021405746113633824]
["2019-12-10T19:04:23", 0.0024248317208396637]
["2019-12-10T19:05:31", 0.0023931006299902744]
["2019-12-10T19:06:41", 0.002093278199112499]
```

I want results similar to the attached.[image]

Comment: Have you considered to use Highstock instead of the regular Highcharts charts? It has implemented zoom which you want to create by default: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Yes. I am using Highstocks

Comment: to show your data from one period you will need to use a larger data set than the shared one. The wanted period you can set by using the `setExtreme` callback. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.events.setExtremes and here is a simple demo showed how to parse your data set: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o58kf0v1/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Thanks